# How to validate a dropdown select

Tags: cakephp, select, validation

I have a form with multiple inputs and a dropdown select :

```
echo $this->Form->input("field",array(
  "name" => "data[Post][project_id]",
  "options" => $proTab,
  "empty" => "Sélectionnez un projet",
  "div" => "control-group",
  "label" => array(
    "class" => "control-label",
    "text" => "Projet : "
  ),
  "between" => "<div class='controls'>",
  "after" => "</div>"
));
```

Which has different option from an user to another.

I've tried to validate it like :

```
"data[Post][project_id]" => array(
  array(
    "rule" => "notEmpty",
    "message" => "Veuillez choisir un projet",
    "allowEmpty" => false
  )
)
```

But, doesn't seem to work. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that will be saved from the **Post** model itself, you must create your form like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input("project_id", array(
    "options" => $proTab,
    "empty" => "Sélectionnez un projet",
    "div" => "control-group",
    "label" => array(
        "class" => "control-label",
        "text" => "Projet : "
    ),
    "between" => "<div class='controls'>",
    "after" => "</div>"
));
```

Do not need the attribute **name**, the first parameter is the definition of the **name** and **id** of field. Will generate this:

```
<select name="data[Post][project_id]" id="PostProjectId">
```

And validation on your **Post** model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'project_id' => array(
        'notEmpty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            'message' => 'Veuillez choisir un projet',
            'allowEmpty' => false
        ),
    ),
);
```

Hope this helps.